# How to debug problems in XAML/WPF controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to build a maintenance form in WPF, using Telerik's WPF controls.  The idea is to have a grid and a form that are bound to the same collection.  Changes to the grid should be immediately reflected in the form, and vice versa.  An online example using Telerik's Silverlight controls is [here](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#DataForm/ICollectionViewSynchronization).

My specific problem is that when I enter a new record (by clicking on the "Add" icon in the upper-right of the DataForm), the record is added to both the grid and to the form's collection, but it seems to break the synchronization.  The new row in the grid stays highlighted, like the grid thinks it's not done being edited, and while changes to the current record in the form are reflected in the grid, changes to the current record in the grid are no longer being reflected in the form.

But my real problem is more general than that.  WPF controls, like Telerik's, are heavily dependent on binding, and in having what they bind to support specific behaviors.  In this case, the underlying record needs to support INotifyIEditableObject, so that when the user hits the Cancel button on the form, the EditCancel method on the record can be called.  Which is then responsible for setting its properties back to what they had been, and then raising a NotifyPropertyChanged event, so that controls that are informed that they have been so set.

When I didn't have EditCancel working right, I would hit cancel on the form and the values in the grid would not be changed.  My guess as to what is going on with the inserts is that something in either my collection or by records doesn't support whatever it is that makes this work.  The grid doesn't know that the form has finished editing the record because either my record or the collection hasn't told it.

And here's the real question: how can I find out what these third-party controls are expecting?  Telerik's RadGrid can be bound to pretty much anything that can be IEnumerated.  But all this neat enhanced functionality depends upon being bound to collections that are very much more specific.  I don't get errors, when I bind to a collection that lacks facilities that are needed for certain functions to work, I just get a control that doesn't work.

How can I tell, when working with someone else's control, for which I do not have source code, what functionality it requires, in the objects it binds to?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to browse [Telerik's documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/introduction.html) or ask on their [support forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx)

If that doesn't work, I like to use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) for debugging WPF's Visual Tree and [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) for looking through compiled libraries